# autoit- How to minimize windows open on ff.au3?

Tags: autoit

Here my code:

```
#Include <FF.au3>

_FFStart()

If _FFIsConnected() Then
    $sStringToSearch = "www.google.com"
    sleep (2000)
    If _FFSearch($sStringToSearch) Then
        ; add a new tab with an URL
        _FFWindowOpen("http://ff-au3-example.thorsten-willert.de/")
        Sleep(1000)
        _FFWindowOpen("www.msn.com")
        Sleep(1000)
        _FFWindowOpen("www.yahoo.com")
        Sleep(1000)
        _FFWindowOpen("google.com")
    EndIf
Else
EndIf
```

According to the script, when I visit google, it would open the first link followed by the other links; now how do I have the windows minimized once they are open.

Also I keep getting ErrorstdOut any solutions to this?

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you are trying to accomplish? Also, since you are using a 3rd party include you should consider to give a source on the web to that include.

Answer (score 2):

Try WinSetState ( "title", "text", flag ) 
Here is the link for the api: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm

A sample is :
WinSetState("Calculator", "", @SW_MINIMIZE )